# Has anyone used a grip a zip to prevent theft (airports and hotels) while traveling?

Tags: luggage, tsa

I am interested in a product: http://www.gripazip.com has anyone used and were you happy with product?

Comment: Would NOT recommend it.

Comment: If someone wants to break into your bag they will just cut through the zip. I suppose it might stop someone doing this discreetly but it isn't going to stop anyone determined.

Comment: I'd never met zip a grip BUT a loko at their site shows that the aim is NOT principally zip security but is preventing bags being able to be opened and resealed without it being evident that it has been done. Cut bags and unsealed zips make it evident that someone has visited. To make the ballpoint pen attack in-obvious you have to be able to slide the slider along the open section to reseal it. A lock that is also locked toa handle etc will stop that. Most cheap suitcase locks are easily opened by professionals. The ZaG stops that  - as long as the TSA lock is not openable by the bad guys.

Answer (score 2):

It is fairly trivial to open zips with a ballpoint pen and even close them later without any visible trace like shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5mvvZl6pLI

This zip a grip thing would not be very helpful against a determined person

[image]
[image]